# Closing PowerPoint After Slidshow finished

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I use the following code to show and close a PowerPoint-slide:

```
private void StartSlideshow() {
    var opApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    ppApp.SlideShowEnd += PpApp_SlideShowEnd;

    var ppPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open(_filename, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    var settings = ppPresentation.SlideShowSettings;
    settings.Run();
}

private void PpApp_SlideShowEnd(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation Pres)  {
    Pres.Saved = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    Pres.Close();
    Pres.Application.Quit();
}
```

Now when I try to close the application (`Pres.Application.Quit()`) I receive the following Exception:

```
Application (unknown member) : Invalid request.  This operation cannot be performed in this event handler.
```

I have a clue why this fails (trying to kill the application that created the event), but if I don't run this command, PowerPoint stays open.

What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
Pres.Close();
Pres.Application.Quit();
```

This first closes the presentation, which destroys the presentation object, then tries to access the non-existent presentation object's parent Application object. I suspect this will work better:

```
Pres.Close();
ppApp.Quit();
```

There will never be more than one instance of PowerPoint in ordinary circumstances; you might want to verify that the application object's Presentations.Count property is 0 after your Pres.Close.  If it's not 0, the user may have already had PPT and another file open, so you may not want to abruptly close the application.